# Is there a conductive tape product that conducts from top to bottom?

Tags: conductive

I have an application where I need to place something conductive, like aluminum foil, to a contact where an object will be sliding onto.  So it needs to be adhesive on one side, yet conduct from the top side to the bottom side.

What product will do this or can be modified to do this?  Both thinness and durability are helpful variables but the requirements do not appear high.

Comment: @eruditass, I changed your title, as you want to know if a product is conductive, not if a product marketed as conductive tape is conductive.

Comment: @Kortuk, any product that will serve the purpose is a viable option that I want to know about.

Comment: I know, but your question implied that you have conductive tape and want to know if it is conductive. Another good question might be, Is there a conductive tape product and then have details in the question about what you need specifically?

Comment: @Eruditass, Glad to see people are finding you answers now.

Comment: There's no option to have the object roll using conductive wheels? It would make it a lot easier on the contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kortuk.  @pfyon, this is a DIY hack for objects that are already made.  However, I don't believe the durability requirements are very high: the pins appear to be dampened with a spring and foil does not appear to rip with the first couple insertion cycles and occasional replacement is not a big deal.

Comment: Question title makes it sounds like you want tape that doubles as a diode :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is foil tape with conductive *adhesive* - used for EMI shielding. Most foil tapes that I've found are not made this way, however 3M does have a range specifically for this purpose.

[3M™ EMI Aluminum Foil Shielding Tape 1170, Conductive Acrylic Adhesive](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/electronics/home/productsandservices/products/ProductNavigator/TapeReel/?PC_7_RJH9U5230GE3E02LECIE20KAB4_nid=4LT3S54QPSbeRQ89J1RQDXgl)

You can find it through various suppliers:

- [Farnell](http://au.element14.com/3m/1170/tape-adhesive-aluminium-19mm/dp/1208990?Ntt=1208990) (now Element 14 in
  AU/NZ)
- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000WRJIE)

**Edit:** You mention a sliding contact, so I thought it was worth mentioning that this product is just like aluminium foil - so may not be durable enough for that application. YMMV.